# Synchronizing with monitor refreshes without vsync

Tags: winapi, opengl, directx, direct3d

What is the preferred way of synchronizing with monitor refreshes, when vsync is not an option? We enable vsync, however, some users disable it in driver settings, and those override app preferences. We need reliable predictable frame lengths to simulate the world correctly, do some visual effects, and synchronize audio (more precisely, we need to estimate how long a frame is going to be on screen, and when it will be on screen).

Is there any way to force drivers to enable vsync despite what the user set in the driver? Or to ask Windows when a monitor rerfesh is going to happen? We have issues with manual sleeping when our frame boundaries line up closely to vblank. It causes occasional missed frames, and up to 1 extra frame of input latency.

We mainly use OpenGL, but Direct3D advice is also appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like have things backwards. You do not want to rely on external sources to provide a steady clock, in order to match up reality with your internal state. Instead, write your system in a way that establishes reality (a rendered frame including synchronized assets) based on the current time. This system is not susceptible to a user opting in to or out of vsync.

Comment: @IInspectable There is no way to do effects like motion blur correctly or synchronize audio without knowing when it's going to be on screen and properly accounting for that time. I'm not saying I want to rely on other sources to synchronize for me, I just want to know when my image is probably going to be on screen. That's not something you can avoid.

Comment: If you want to know the approximate time your image will be on screen, extrapolate the past, however elaborate you want your extrapolation algorithm to be. I don't see how vsync will make the job any easier. It's just a way of quantizing your timing. You can quantize your timing just as well without vsync.

Comment: @IInspectable I can't extrapolate my timing if my timing is in no way connected to when images are displayed. A period of 16 milliseconds is meaningless if the image isn't displayed at the start of that period. Choosing just any start causes input lag and possibly tearing. Vsync gives the application means of finding out when the image appeared on the monitor.

Comment: @IInspectable Note that I'm ok with implementing vsync myself, but I need to find out when the monitor does that. That's a very exact time, not something the application can just make up.

Comment: @Kalinovcic: "*There is no way to do effects like motion blur correctly or synchronize audio without knowing when it's going to be on screen and properly accounting for that time.*" How off do you expect to be? 16ms? 32ms? Most people can't tell if your audio is off by such a small time. As for motion blur, accurate timing is not necessary; you can just pick a number and you'll probably be close. "*Choosing just any start causes input lag and possibly tearing.*" Yes. Tearing is what can happen when you don't have vsync. They asked for it, so give them what they asked for.

Comment: Basically, applications do not attempt to synchronize themselves to vsync in general. This is true of most games, etc. This is why games *don't* slow down when they start to drop frames.

Comment: You clearly need to implement framerate-independent game loop (that is make application run at the same rate regardless of presentation FPS), however proper targeting of presentation without vsync can be tricky. I'm not sure whether it makes sense to fight with users that disable vsync by force.

Comment: "Most people can't tell if your audio is off by such a small time."

ugh, no. averagely-trained musicians can feel things are off around 6-8 ms. 32ms is in the "terrible" ballpark.

Answer (score 1):

You should not build your application's timing on the basis of vsync and exact timings of frame presentation. Games don't do that these days and have not do so for quite some time. This is what allows them to keep a consistent speed even if they start dropping frames; because their timing, physics computations, AI, etc isn't based on when a frame gets displayed but instead on actual timing.

Game frame timings are typically sufficiently small (less than 50ms) that human beings cannot detect any audio/video synchronization issues. So if you want to display an image that should have a sound played alongside it, as long as the sound starts within about 30ms or so of the image, you're fine.

Oh and don't bother trying to switch to Vulkan/D3D12 to resolve this problem. They don't. Vulkan in particular decouples presentation from other tasks, making it basically impossible to know the exact time when an image starts appearing on the screen. You give Vulkan an image, and it presents it... at whatever is the next most opportune moment. You get some control over how that moment gets chosen, but even those choices can be restricted based on factors outside of your control.

Design your program to avoid the need for rigid vsync. Use internal timings instead.

Comment: How would using internal timing solve frame drops? If I measure that the last frame took 30 ms instead of 16 ms because it was too slow, I don't want to use that timing for simulation now, because this frame is unlikely to be slow again, so it would just be a frame that is displayed for 16 ms but advances the world by 30 ms. I could do all simulation on a separate thread, and I do a lot of it, but then there are complications surrounding extrapolation of entity positions and animations, since display time and real time don't match up.

Comment: @Kalinovcic: It solves frame drops by *not caring about frame drops*. The simulation should *always* run at a particular timing: 15fps, 30fps, 60fps, whatever. How many pictures you show between simulation frames is irrelevant. You interpolate between two frames of the simulation when you decide to render, and the time of interpolation is based on how long it has been since the last render. Or more specifically, how much time passed since the last time you started to render.

Comment: I understand that doing this would make the simulated time be equal to elapsed time across all frames, but I'm not sure that's actually desirable... This seems like introducing another "extra simulation" spike to correct for the previous lag spike.

Comment: @kal: The point is that your code should not care about spikes **at all**. It should just render, given the current wall clock time (or delta, based on some arbitrarily chosen origin). If you drop a frame, it will not affect future frames.

Comment: This answer is rather misleading. Use of framerate-independent game loop does not mean that application does not need to care about exact timings of frame presentation anymore. Games these days not only tend to target upcoming time of presentation instead of current (or game local) time but also employ sophisticated means of forward prediction in attempt to reduce latency. And frame timings are quite tight, especially in VR where a failure to present a frame within 8 / 11ms window will give a player severe motion sickness.